# Tabs are displayed differently in ios phone and tablet

Tags: ios, iphone, xamarin, ios-simulator

My Xamarin Forms app uses IconizedTabbedPages.  When testing through the simulators, the tabs look like the following in portrait and landscape modes:
[iPhone 7 Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/3F5Vq.png)
and:[iPhone 7 Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/d5WZY.png)
however on a iPad tablet, it looks like:
[iPad Pro Portrait](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7gNd2.png) and [iPad Pro Landscape](https://i.stack.imgur.com/mEn9G.png).

The separatation/spacing between tab names/icons are not correct.  How can I fix this?

Comment: Are you using default tabbar or custom tabbar?

Comment: No, aside from using IconizedTabbedPage plugin, it is standard xamarin forms.  There is not a custom renderer.